# Vertica: improve query performance joining to external table

Tags: sql, database, performance, parquet, vertica

I am running a query on a vertica cluster which is taking overnight.  I'd like to know what I can do to improve performance.  My query consists of a small table (21k rows) with a list of ID's joined to a large table (>14bn rows) on a matching field (pat_id).  I'd like to return all rows in the large table which have an ID in my small reference table.  The large table is stored as an external parquet file.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Explain statement below:

```
explain select ims.* from juv_arthritis_pts juv join dwdev1_data.IMS_claims ims on juv.pat_id = ims.pat_id

Access Path:
+-JOIN HASH [Cost: 2K, Rows: 21K (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 1) Outer (RESEGMENT)(LOCAL ROUND ROBIN)
|  Join Cond: (juv.pat_id = ims.pat_id)
|  Execute on: v_dwp1_node0001, v_dwp1_node0002, v_dwp1_node0003, v_dwp1_node0005
| +-- Outer -> LOAD  EXTERNAL TABLE [Cost: 0, Rows: 10K (NO STATISTICS)] (PATH ID: 2)
| |      Table: IMS_claims
| |      copy from '/mapr/mapr.XXX.local/Environments/svc.dwdev1/data/ims_claims.final/*/*' PARQUET
| |      Execute on: Query Initiator
| +-- Inner -> STORAGE ACCESS for juv [Cost: 33, Rows: 21K] (PATH ID: 3)
| |      Projection: X.juv_arthritis_pts_b0
| |      Materialize: X.pat_id
| |      Execute on: v_dwp1_node0001, v_dwp1_node0002, v_dwp1_node0003
| +---> STORAGE ACCESS for juv (REPLACEMENT FOR DOWN NODE) [Cost: 49, Rows: 21K]
| |      Projection: X.juv_arthritis_pts_b1
| |      Materialize: juv.pat_id
| |      Execute on: v_dwp1_node0001, v_dwp1_node0005
```

Comment: can you show a verbose explain plan? that might give more detail where your cost is at. `explain verbose select * from table` .